# Was Roy the only human to board the ship?

Tags: close-encounters-of-the-third-kind

At the end of Close Encounters OTTK, Roy Neary gets recruited last-minute into the group of red-suited volunteers that are supposed to go with the aliens. When they approach the ship they line up **right in front** of the open bay. Roy gets singled out by the race of small aliens and taken up personally. Then the next time we get a wide shot of the ship, the rest of red suits are gone.

**While we only actually see Roy boarding with the aliens, did the rest of the group go as well?**

You can see the red suits' positioning to the ship in this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYtSsBCYByk) (~00:15).

Then the rest of them no longer in the area in this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeeZA4B1qyI) (~01:15).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The astronauts accompanied him

From the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/975119.Close_Encounters_Of_The_Third_Kind) (written by Stephen Spielberg)

> *Roy turned and took the first step forward. Then he started walking slowly, then faster toward the ship’s negative gravity zone, and the
> fiery, lighted opening. **The twelve astronauts began to follow
> him.***
>
> ***The little humanoids formed a blinking, twittering file on either side of the column of astronauts and accompanied them up the
> brilliantly lighted stairway toward the glowing interior of the great
> mother ship.***
>
> *One little creature separated himself from the procession and flowed over to Lacombe. He reached out one armlike thing and made the first
> of the hand signs, corresponding to the first note. Lacombe, deeply
> moved, responded. Then the creature and the Frenchman went through the
> other four hand signs.*
>
> *Lacombe looked down into its . . . face. It was changing—from something embryonic, unformed, into a face of something a thousand
> years old. Suddenly, Lacombe knew that all the wisdom, all the
> superintelligence, the experience that it had to take to build these
> vehicles, to travel these dozens of light years was there in the aging
> countenance and the . . . yes, the smile of this fantastic little
> creature.*
>
> *Lacombe smiled back, and then the little thing flowed away after the others into the phantom ship. Neary was almost inside now. Incredibly,
> he was thinking and hearing a song in his head. It was from Pinocchio.
> When you wish upon a star, Makes no difference who you are. Anything
> your heart desires will come . . . to . . . you. He took another step
> up the ramp of fiery brilliance into the center of the starship.
> Around him the blaze was almost blinding, yet he seemed to be able to
> see . . . everything. And the music in his head grew louder. If your
> heart is in your dream, No request is too extreme, When you wish upon
> a star as dreamers do.*
>
> ***Roy turned to make sure the twelve astronauts were still with him. Then he waved one last time to Lacombe and to Jillian and Barry. He
> hoped they could still see him. Outside, on the cement strip, the
> figures of Neary, the astronauts, the little creatures, were
> dematerializing into fiery light and energy.***

And from the [film's screenplay](https://indiegroundfilms.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/close-encounters-of-the-third-kind.pdf)

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>"The inside light burns brighter and brighter as one after another the twenty volunteers disappear into the brilliant opening"</sup></sub>